# Check a server every X time and see if somthing new is added

Tags: android, webserver

I need my android app to

check a server every X time and see if something new is added  - and
 then use the new data that added.

how the hell i do it >?

what kind of server you suggest I should use?  (the data is only in a "string" Format)

samples will be helpful !

thx in advance Tom.

Comment: alarmmanager + http headers (lastmodification and if-modified-since)

Comment: I would suggest using a service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think it will be efficient. Consider the more user you have, it will query your server like crazy.

If the data is just String, put that in a HTML webpage or even a txt file will do. Every time you wanna query, read that HTML page or download that txt file.

On any kind of OS, Apache is quite nice. I suggest you to start there.

Anyway, I will suggest you to rethink your approach if the X is a really small number like every 5 second. If it's like one or two days, you will be fine.

Comment: thx for answering - 
my app is only used 2 smartphones so i dont think it should be a problem - 
but how do i do it - 
how do i check the server (the html web page) evrey X time ?


thx in advance ,  Tom.

Comment: @user1581901 Just how big is that X? seconds, minutes, or days? If it's seconds, I will say you right a class to do that. If minutes or more, use AlarmManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html )

Comment: the X is about 2-4 min - so you suggest me to use AlarmManger ?

Comment: @user1581901 Yes, making a class of yours cost time, and it wouldn't be as efficient as using a built-in service.
(If it's like 2 second, then the time will be up before the system receives your request LOL)

Answer (score 0):

if you have your own server, just use GCM and push a message to the phone that tells it there is something new. then it can go get it. that will use less battery and data traffic.

Comment: He said he has only two phones that needs the data. In my point of view, using push message will just add complexity.

Comment: i didn't say it was simpler, i said it was more efficient. i hate apps that drain my battery, so using GCM to stop that is worth the (slight) added complexity - at least to me

Comment: True. But anyway, I really think it depends on its interval which he really refuse to tell us.

Comment: I think I will use service + http headers .. thanks you for helping !

Comment: no problem. but it will drain your battery fast to ping the server every 2-4 minutes. you should look up Reto Meier's ProTips talks from the last couple years at Google I/O

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shane Hsu, it would be better to use the Push Service (GCM) from Google (http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). If this is a overkill just do a http-request:

```
private void loadData(String url){
    String result = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

            BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String str = "";
            if((str = inStream.readLine()) != null){
                    result = str;
            }


            inStream.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            result = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Because this tasks takes long to excecute, you should put it in a Thread. Call it like this:

```
new Thread(){
  public void run() {
    loadData("your url"); // save the result in some instance variable
  }
}.start();
```